# Lacking understanding of some properties of the improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

Let $f:[1,\infty)$ a continuious and non-negative function s.t. 
$\int_1^\infty f(x)$ converges.

I don't understand why the existence of $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f($x)
neccessairly means that $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f($x) = 0.(why?)

Plus, Does $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = 0$
even if the assumption of the existence of is not given?(why?)

Lastly, Is the function $f$ bounded over the line $[1,\infty)$?(why?)

Thanks in adnvance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $l:= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)>0$. Then there is $c_1>1$ such that $f(x) \ge l/2$ for $x \ge c_1$. For $u$ with $u>c_1$ we then have

$\int_u^{u+1}f(x) dx \ge l/2$.

If $ 0< \epsilon < l/2$ we have by Cauchy: there is $c_2 \ge c_1$ such that

$\int_u^{u+1}f(x) dx < \epsilon$ for $u>c_2$, a contradiction.

Yes, $f$ is bounded: there is $r>1$ such that $f(x) \le 2l$ for $x>r$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is also bounded on $[1,r]$

Comment: In the part Plus, Does limx→∞f(x)=0 even if the assumption of the existence of is not given?(why?). Can I infer that this is already given by the fact that f(x) is convergent?